# Kubernetes StorageClass not found

Tags: kubernetes, storage-class-specifier, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I am facing issues with Dynamic Storage provisioner.
I have created  storage class (edited)

```
kubectl get sc
NAME                 PROVISIONER             AGE
slow                 kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   12m
standard (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   14m
```

when i create a pvc referring to one of the storage classes, it fails

```
kubectl describe pvc mypvc
Name:          mypvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  slow
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    []
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
Type     Reason              Age   From                         Message
----     ------              ----  ----                         -------
Warning  ProvisioningFailed  8s    persistentvolume-controller  
storageclass.storage.k8s.io "slow" not found
```

Any idea why it fails with

```
storageclass.storage.k8s.io "slow" not found
```

Here is the describe of slow sc

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-04-27T22:19:49Z
  name: slow
  resourceVersion: "665900"
  selfLink: /apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/slow
  uid: 19ab37b5-4a69-11e8-8f68-021e47d98090
parameters:
  fsType: ext4
  iopsPerGB: "10"
  type: io1
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

Comment: Can you update your question with `kubectl get -o yaml sc slow`; my hypothesis is that `slow` might be in a different `apiVersion` from `storageclass.storage.k8s.io`

Comment: `kubectl get sc slow -o yaml
    apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
    kind: StorageClass
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: 2018-04-27T22:19:49Z
      name: slow
      resourceVersion: "665900"
      selfLink: /apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/slow
      uid: 19ab37b5-4a69-11e8-8f68-021e47d98090
    parameters:
      fsType: ext4
      iopsPerGB: "10"
      type: io1
    provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
    reclaimPolicy: Delete`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Updated the question with the `get -o yaml` for slow storageclass

Comment: Do you have [`DefaultStorageClass`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic) in the `--enable-admission-plugins` for your apiservers?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Yes, i have it enabled.
`--admission-control=DefaultStorageClass,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota,PodPreset,Initializers,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook`

Answer (score 2):

ok. I found the answer. I didnt enable the storage api as part of runtimeconfigs for apiserver

```
--runtime-config=storage.k8s.io/v1=true
```

Adding the above line solved the issue